# WSL2 ip address range conflicts with my corporate VPN

Tags: vpn, wsl-2

I recently started using WSL2 instead of Virtual Box to run Linux on my PC. Sometimes I need to connect to git repositories that exist on my corporate VPN internal network. But recently WSL2 started giving the VM an address range that conflicts with my corporate VPN, so when the VPN is not connected the Linux system can communicate fine with the internet, but as soon as I go onto the VPN the Linux system can no longer communicate with the internet or host on the internal network because the range it is using (e.g. 172.18.230.215/20 ) is also advertised by the VPN as a range on the internal network.

Is there a way to force WSL2 to use only specific private ranges so I can find a range that does not conflict with the corp internal network?

Comment: any solution? @John S

Comment: I never found a way to force the WSL2 range to be what I want but the problem sort of resolved itself as the system started randomly selecting one that didn't conflict - not very useful I'm afraid :-(

Comment: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530567/windows-wsl2-and-vpn-networking/72530568#72530568

Comment: @dannylee8 "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation"

Comment: Hi @benni - take a look at these two blog posts.  This guy is awesome:
https://janovesk.com/wsl/2022/01/24/wsl2-and-vpn-dns.html
https://janovesk.com/wsl/2022/01/21/wsl2-and-vpn-routing.html
I've actually ended up just using a batch script to switch between wsl1 and wsl2 bc its easier.  (wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 1 and 2)  wsl --list to see your installed versions.  Wsl1 when i need internet access. Wsl2 when I want to run docker.  Somedays the internet just works in wsl2